# django-transmeta: How to localize sitemaps

Tags: python, django

I'm making simple webblog system translated into 2 languages. It contains 2 models Article (translated name and description here) and Category (translated name here)

How do I generate a sitemap one per category per language?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am a developer of django-transmeta.

I think that your problem is that you wat use the same template and in Django is impossible something like this:

```
{{ content.title_{{ lang }} }}
```

A solution would be have a template for each lang. But it's a ugly solution.

Other solution, could be create a [templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/) and in your template have something like this:

```
{% transmeta content "title" lang %}
```